# np.ma.average() to avoid DivideByZero error

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I am taking means of quantities like:

```
mean = np.ma.average(X,weights=weights, axis=1)
```

`X` is a 2-dim array of 100 col, 1000 rows. `weights` has the same shape and the result `mean` is 1000 rows as expected. The advantage over np.average() is that for rows where the weights are all 0, I don't get a divide by zero error. And then when I plot the average like so, it looks good.

```
plt.hist(mean)
```

I do not want the `mean = 0` when all the weights are 0, instead I want that row to be skipped in plotting. Is this what's happening? Or am I plotting extra 0s when the weights are 0?

@anishtain4 gives a alternate solution that does exactly what's required. But I want to know if it is wrong to use `np.ma` functions instead. Could it do something unintended?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the index of rows where not all of the weights are zero, then filter the output using that:

```
ind=np.any(weights,axis=1)
ans=np.mean(X*weights,axis=1)[ind]
```

**Edit:**

To keep the dimension the same and skip invalid rows in plots, you can simply set them to `np.nan`. However the results of those rows won't make any sense (but I don't think this is important). So the code will look like:

```
ind=~np.any(weights,axis=1)
weights[ind]=np.nan
ans=np.mean(x*weights,axis=1)
plt.plot(ans)
```

Comment: Yes but this way I change the shape. I want to keep track of the `NAN` rows as well for other calculations. For example if I want to then do `ans1 - Y`, I can't, because `Y` will have 1000 rows.

Comment: @user7867665 So you want to keep the shape the same, the results of those rows doesn't matter, and you want those rows to be skipped in plotting?

Comment: yes exactly. I can achieve this with `numpy.ma` functions. Is there any danger of unintended consequences?

Comment: Your Edit gives the correct answer, but just to be complete, I want to know specifically if it is wrong to do the same with `numpy.ma`